# WPF Main function breakpoint isn't hitting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, program-entry-point, breakpoints

With an out of the box WPF application, I changed the App file build action from `ApplicationDefinition` to `Page`.

Then I created a new class file within the project :

```
public partial class App{
    [STAThread( )]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode( )]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode( "PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0" )]
    public static void Main( ){
        Console.WriteLine( "Insert Break Point Here" );
    }
}
```

The console is printing the line, so it's hitting the line, but the breakpoint isn't catching.

This is just a mockup since I have a more complex program with which I am having a similar issue.

Why isn't the break point catching?

Comment: WPF doesn't recognize main method as the entry point is defined somewhere else. are you sure the line is being printed out? how about trying to throw an exception instead of write line

Comment: @Steve Yes it does. If you create a project out of the box, and look into the obj/debug directory, you will find several .cs files, in which one is contained a Main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - It's the line

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode( )]
```

Commenting out that line, the break points hit.

Comment: It doesn't work. There is a warning on the breakpoint when starting debugging saying that symbols are not loaded for that document, thus the breakpoint will not been hit.

Answer (score 0):

You may also have to uncheck 'optimize code' under project properties (right-click on project name) / Build